# help in webservices in android

Tags: android, web-services

can anybody please provide me some code that could help me. actually i am trying to work on web services. i have a web service with login aand register methods . now in my android app how can i get to those login and register methods. pelase demonstrate..

Comment: [Here you go.](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=using+web+service+from+android)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have been trying to do the same. There is k-SOAP2 which some people have used, but unfortunately it didn't work for me. So I came up with the next best thing, i.e. putting in a Servlet to act as a go between between the android client and the web service.

Hope this helps.

Comment: can u provide some more details